# Java Heap Behaviour

Tags: java, oracle, memory, jvm, heap-memory

Given a java memory configuration like the following

```
 -Xmx2048m -Xms512m
```

What would be the behaviour of the VM when memory usage increases past 512m? Is there a particular algorithm that it follows? ie. Does it go straight to the max, does it double, does it go in increments, or does it only allocate as it needs memory? How expensive an operation is it?

I'm looking specifically at the Oracle/Sun JVM, version 1.6. I assume this is documented on the Oracle website somewhere, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: It definitely doesn't go straight to the max.

Comment: You're defining the minimum + maximum. It will be at least 512mb but with a cap of 2048mb.

Comment: From my understanding, the minimum memory value is allocated when the JVM starts up - So, at startup, it consumes 512m from the host operating system to utilise for its own use. What I don't understand is when it needs more than 512m, how much does it take, and how does it take it? For example - The JVM needs 750mb - Will it consume 750mb exactly, or grow to 1024mb? Or follow some other behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the garbage collector's job to decide when resizing is necessary, so it is determined by the GC parameter 'MinFreeHeapRatio.'  If the GC needs more space, it will grow to a size where the % of heap specified by that value is available.

A typical value on a modern platform is 40ish, so if you start at 512MB and have less than 40% free, meaning you exceeded ~308MB, it will increase until 40% is free again. So say after collection there are still 400MB worth of live objects, your heap will go up to ~667MB.  (Yes it is named ratio but expects a % value as argument... search me!)

Note this is a bit inexact, the garbage collector is "generational" and actually can resize individual generations, but it also has forced ratios between generations sizes and if your objects are distributed between long lived and short lived in roughly the way it estimates, it works out pretty well for back of the envelope.

This applies to defaults in Java 6.  If you use custom garbage collector config it may be different.  You can read about that here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#generation_sizing.total_heap

(The "expense" of the operation kind of depends on the operating system and what else is going on.  If the system is loaded down and the OS has to do some swapping to make a contiguous block of memory for you, then it could be very expensive!)

Answer (score 2):

Use of `-verbose:gc` and/or `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` options should give you many finer details.

Here is an example output with the `-verbose:gc` option switched on:

```
[GC 325407K->83000K(776768K), 0.2300771 secs]
[GC 325816K->83372K(776768K), 0.2454258 secs]
[Full GC 267628K->83769K(776768K), 1.8479984 secs]
```

An explanation of the above taken from the official [document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html):

> Here we see two minor collections followed by one major collection.
>   The numbers before and after the arrow (e.g., `325407K->83000K` from the
>   first line) indicate the combined size of live objects before and
>   after garbage collection, respectively. After minor collections the
>   size includes some objects that are garbage (no longer alive) but that
>   cannot be reclaimed. These objects are either contained in the tenured
>   generation, or referenced from the tenured or permanent generations.
>
> The next number in parentheses (e.g., (`776768K`) again from the first
>   line) is the committed size of the heap: the amount of space usable
>   for java objects without requesting more memory from the operating
>   system. Note that this number does not include one of the survivor
>   spaces, since only one can be used at any given time, and also does
>   not include the permanent generation, which holds metadata used by the
>   virtual machine.
>
> The last item on the line (e.g., `0.2300771 secs`) indicates the time
>   taken to perform the collection; in this case approximately a quarter
>   of a second.
>
> The format for the major collection in the third line is similar.

Running an application this way along with updating minimum and maximum heap sizes can give good insight into heap allocation and garbage collection patterns of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

its to be noted that JVM on Initialization virtually reserves maximum address space but does not allocate physical memory. Typically the JVM will allocate space into Old  and Young generation. There are intermidatory space in the Young Generation . The new objects invoked are contained in the Young Generation.

When the intermidatory space is filled up , GC is invoked which moves reference Objects to one of the Intermidatory space called Survivor Space in the Young Generation Segment. The GC might follow "stop-the-world" by saving thread's state algorithm or an alogorithm so the processes keep running(?).

When the Survivor space fills JVM invokes a full GC.